# Graph API responded mismatched information

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I got HTTP 429 (Too Many Requests) when getting drive root, but I expected the http status should be 400 (Bad Request).

Is this server issue ?

```
2023-05-06T15:37:28Z
GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ddcae56d-808b-4d1c-9b9f-a903c765cf66/drive/root

HTTP 429
BODY 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2023-05-06T15:37:28",
      "request-id": "e7162a72-c7b7-457c-a75c-6822276c3c16",
      "client-request-id": "e7162a72-c7b7-457c-a75c-6822276c3c16"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the curl debug log (I deleted the access token)

This account always getting 429, but other accounts got 400 (expected).

```
curl -v -L 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive' --header 'Authorization: Bearer '
*   Trying 20.190.144.171...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to graph.microsoft.com (20.190.144.171) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):

* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; CN=graph.microsoft.com
*  start date: Mar  3 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Mar  3 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "graph.microsoft.com" matched cert's "graph.microsoft.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
> GET /v1.0/me/drive HTTP/1.1
> Host: graph.microsoft.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer 
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
< HTTP/1.1 429
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< request-id: 13bee41a-4f98-4944-ba06-d30f299058b7
< client-request-id: 13bee41a-4f98-4944-ba06-d30f299058b7
< x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Korea Central","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"SE1PEPF00000915"}}
< Date: Mon, 15 May 2023 02:00:26 GMT
<
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Unknown (23):
* Connection #0 to host graph.microsoft.com left intact
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.","innerError":{"date":"2023-05-15T02:00:26","request-id":"13bee41a-4f98-4944-ba06-d30f299058b7","client-request-id":"13bee41a-4f98-4944-ba06-d30f299058b7"}}}
```

Anyone knows why ?

Comment: Hi Wen Hsiao, are there other endpoints in your environment that are being requested?

Comment: @ZehuiYao I added details and it looks like no other endpoints are being requested